# Scientist builds monitoring robot

Tags: story-identification, aliens, robots, androids

Anyone remember a movie about a scientist who builds a mysterious android/robot (of alien design) that ends up monitoring all Earth's communications to "help" our planet solve its problems? Maybe from late 50's, early 60's, might have been a TV movie.

Answer (score 2):

That could be [The Questor Tapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Questor_Tapes), (1974), a television movie produced by Gene Roddenberry.  It's about an android designed by a scientist who has disappeared.  The government group building the android tries to decypher the programming tape left by the designer, but they accidentally erase half of it, and the android has to try to find the purpose for which he was created.  It turns out the designer was an android as well, in a long line of androids that created their successors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I downloaded and watched The Questor Tapes.  Not the right movie.  One scene I distinctly remember from the movie I'm seeking had the android monitoring TV broadcasts on multiple screens to keep track of and "analyze" human activity. No such scene in Questor - and I'm sure I would have remembered Mike Farrell of M.A.S.H. fame.  Questor was fun though, thanks, Ted